# configuring kernel build

Tags: kernel, compiling

I hope this is the right place for such question (if not please tell me and I'll move the question).

I am building ubuntu kernel,
I use instructions in 
http://www.variwiki.com/index.php?title=DART_Ubuntu_GS

The instruction steps says to configure with :

```
   fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

But:

1. I don't see where it is configured for omap dart board and:
2. there is no  .config in kernel folder.
3. there is no module.symvers in kernel home folder only in some /debian folder inside. this file is required when building external module.

Does it all make sense, or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks,
Ran

Comment: I think it is a correct place for this question.

Comment: Are you asking about `ARCH_OMAP` kernel config?

Comment: The manual you referred is quite clear. Just do it. You do not have to edit any configs in that case.

Comment: I am used to .config in the kernel folder. there is none, and I fail to build external module.

Comment: It is OK to have `.config` in `debian`.